# vim/nvim line spacing when printing

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to use nvim for everything, including writing, and all is great but the text is too crammed when I print it out.

Is it possible to adjust the line spacing when printing with `:hardcopy`?

My idea of a kludge fix would be to insert a second newline character for every carriage return, including those automatically inserted by line wrapping. Is this possible?

Comment: You could do `:g/^/norm o` but that doesn't work for wraps also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the least frustrating ways to do it would be to use a tool like `pandoc` to convert the text (for example Markdown) to whatever format you need — preferably PDF. However, `pandoc` uses LaTeX to create the resulting PDF, so regarding the styling you would have to tinker with supplying it a template or other options.

You can do it even easier with (for example) a Node.js tool called [mdpdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdpdf). After installation, just run

```
mdpdf file.md --style styles.css
```

to supply it with a CSS stylesheet in which you can modify the resulting text output with [every feature CSS permits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference). Using larger line spacing would be something like this:

```
body { line-spacing: 150%; }
```

This results in a 1.5x line spacing for everything in the document.

Of course, you can also set up a custom Vim command to automate this for you, putting something like the following into your `.vimrc`:

```
command MdToPDF !mdpdf %:t --style /full/path/to/styles.css
```

Calling `:MdToPDF` in Vim will then run that command for you.

Finally, if you're happy with the output, just print the PDF.

Comment: While I realize that `vim` was never meant to deal with print formatting, this is actually a pretty decent workflow and a solid stopgap solution. So I'm accepting it even tho it is not a "vim" solution per se. Thanks!